# I'd like to return value after block executed

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

```
- (NSString *) BBB {
    __block NSString *returnValue;

    NSDictionary *queryParameters = @{ @"q" : @"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()"};
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"fql" parameters:queryParameters HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        returnValue = result[@"data"][0][@"uid"];
        NSLog(@"inside block -> %@", returnValue);
    }];

    return returnValue;
}
```

I'd like to return correct value but `FBRequestConnection` is an asynchronous request.
That's make value of `returnValue` is (null) because it's returned before FBRequestConnection's completionBlock is executed.

Comment: Where do you need to return that value? There are few mechanisms to achieve this.

Comment: I have a function 'AAA' to call 'BBB' for this value.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return that value to a specific method, a simple solution could be to move the code that rely on that value to an additional method. Also you could think to set up a waiting indicator. In this case, the user will know that an operation is running.

```
- (void)BBB {    

    __weak SelfType weakSelf = self; // to prevent possible memory leaks if you use ARC

    NSDictionary *queryParameters = @{ @"q" : @"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()"};
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"fql" parameters:queryParameters HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        returnValue = result[@"data"][0][@"uid"];
        NSLog(@"inside block -> %@", returnValue);

        __strong SelfType safeSelf = weakSelf;
        if(safeSelf) {
            // notify that the operation is finished
            [safeSelf DDDWithReturnValue:returnValue];
        }
    }];
}
```

The code I provided works under ARC. If your code is non-ARC enabled use

```
__block SelfType weakSelf = self; // for non-ARC code
```